# 0-1 knapsack with weight equal to capacity rather than smaller or equal

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

In a knapsack problem we usually try to maximise the the value of the goods in the knapsack while keeping the total weight of the goods <= C where C is the capacity of the knapsack. How do I solve the problem when the total weight of the goods should be exactly equal to the capacity of the knapsack = C?

Comment: It's the same, you just stop when it's equal with C.

Comment: @Robert Dnt we start from C and keep subtracting values? in that case stopping when its equal to 0 may not give the right ans. i.e if it becomes 0 then yes it is the answer but if it becomes negative we shud have considered anoathere set of objects itself subtracting after which gives 0

Comment: It can be done that way as well or you can start from 0 and end at C. It's according to your coding style. If your base case is perfect, you will not have any problem in your recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are solving is same but with tighter constraint. The DP solution for the same will be :-

```
DP(n,W) = 0;
Valid(n,W) = false;

if(Valid(n-1,W)) {

    DP(n,W) = DP(n-1,W);
    Valid(n,W) = true;
}

if(Valid(n-1,W-weight[n])) {

     DP(n,W) = max(DP(n,W),DP(n-1,W-weight[n])+value[n]);
     Valid(n,W) = true;
}
```